# Does Amazon DynamoDB supports HTTP/2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

According to https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/2984, it seems Amazon DynamoDB doesn't support HTTP/2. There are other services that support HTTP/2 but not Amazon DynamoDB.

I tested several endpoints from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ddb.html list and they don't seem to support it.

```
$ curl -v --http2-prior-knowledge https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
*   Trying 52.119.233.242:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (52.119.233.242) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
*  start date: Dec  9 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Dec  8 23:59:59 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" matched cert's "dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Server
< Date: Fri, 13 Aug 2021 23:03:18 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 42
< Connection: keep-alive
< x-amzn-RequestId: B0M1S6B7509A9FS62EMN7MV8QJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG
< x-amz-crc32: 3128867991
<
* Connection #0 to host dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com left intact
```

Does anyone know if this is true or why they don't support it?
Couldn't find it in their documentation.

Comment: This sounds like a AWS support question, not a programming question.

Comment: why not to use boto3?

Comment: @balderman boto3 doesn't use http2 either. i believe OP was checking if the DDB service even supported http2 (regardless if boto3 has implemented it) and it does not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DynamoDB indeed does not seem to support HTTP/2 today. I don't think there is a good reason "why". It's just something that Amazon didn't do, and I am guessing they **will** do in the future, because many of their other services, as well as their libraries, support HTTP/2.

More than a year ago I wrote [a blog post](https://www.scylladb.com/2020/05/12/comparing-cql-and-the-dynamodb-api/) comparing the **DynamoDB API** and Cassandra's and Scylla's **CQL** API. One of the downsides I mentioned of the DynamoDB API is exactly the lack of HTTP/2 support, which means you need to open as many connections as the number of concurrent requests you want to make, and that has overheads. I said that:

> The DynamoDB API had to work around its transport’s lack of multiplexing by adding special multi-request operations, namely `BatchGetItem` and `BatchWriteItem` — each can perform multiple operations and return reordered responses. However, these workarounds are more limited and less convenient than generic support for multiplexing.
> Had DynamoDB supported HTTP/2, it would have gained multiplexing as well, and would even gain an advantage over CQL for large requests or responses: The CQL protocol cannot break up a single request or response into chunks, but HTTP/2 does do it, avoiding large latencies for small requests which happen to follow a large request on the same connection. **We predict that in the future, DynamoDB will support HTTP/2. Some other Amazon services already do.**

Comment: This is unfortunate. We are making thousands of put_item requests and cannot use the BatchWriteItem because our requests have conditional expressions. The overhead even with pooling is enormous and unnecessary.

Comment: I tested DDB yesterday with HTTP/1.1 pipelines and worked like a charm with significant better performance. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP-Pipelining. For sure, not a HTTP/2 replacement, but a single connection can be used for multiple concurrent requests.

Comment: It's been awhile, has anything changed here? I'm also unsure of what the HTTP versions various AWS SDKs support. (We mostly use Java)